# Duplicate data from one to another

Tags: excel

I have 2 excel sheets sheet1 and sheet2 where some data/cells are duplicate i need to get these duplicated data/cells in sheet3.

Like **sheet1 A1 abc** and **sheet2 A5 abc** now i need this **"abc" in sheet3**.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to other sheets like this:

```
=Sheet2!A1
```

This refers to the A1 cell of Sheet 2.